# How to start Android AOSP emulator on MAC

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-source

I have downloaded and compiled Android source code per instructions on Android source website (http://source.android.com/source/building.html)

I chose

```
$ lunch full-eng
```

an emulator engineering build and everything has compiled just fine.

Then it says to launch the image inside an emulator just type:

```
The emulator is added to your path automatically by the build process. To run the emulator, type

$ emulator
```

Well, not sure it is added to the path. Typing emulator does not do anything.

However if I go to

```
out/host/darwin-x86/bin/emulator
emulator: ERROR: You did not specify a virtual device name, and the system
directory could not be found.

If you are an Android SDK user, please use '@<name>' or '-avd <name>'
to start a given virtual device (see -help-avd for details).
```

So I am confused ... at this point do I have to create an AVD ? 
How do I create an AVD for this image exactly ?

Has anyone done this on MAC can they supply me with some instructions ?

Thanks

Comment: I would post this question on the google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/android-building

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is any difference on osx, but it is a common error on Linux. After you build the whole AOSP, the building process will add the `<AndroidBase>/out/host/<host-arch>/bin/emulator` into the PATH, but after you restart your computer or open another session, emulator will no longer be in the path.

To fix the "You did not specify a virtual device name, and the system
directory could not be found" error, you can explicitly set ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT to point to your disk image directory. In general, the disk image directory would be `<AndroidBase>/out/target/product/generic`. So

```
$export ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=<ANDROID BASEDIR>/out/target/product/generic/
```

would help.

Actually, you can run

```
. build/envsetup.sh
setpaths
```

It will do a similar work for you.

Comment: hi ! yes running envsetup actuall does resolve all path issues. However the main problem is that when emulator is run it expects some arguments to passed with it. otherwise you get : out/host/darwin-x86/bin/emulator
emulator: ERROR: You did not specify a virtual device name, and the system
directory could not be found.

If you are an Android SDK user, please use '@<name>' or '-avd <name>'
to start a given virtual device (see -help-avd for details).

Comment: so how did you create a AVD for the emulator you built ?

Comment: Generally, you can explicitly use emulator -system system.img -data userdata.img -ramdisk ramdisk.img to start the emulator without creating any avd. If you set ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT as my answer says, the emulator will automatically find those images, so it should work fine. @drlobo

Answer (score 0):

I build with aosp_x86_64-eng and have verified that the following will launch the emulator in a new terminal window:

```
cd /[your AOSP WORKING_DIRECTORY]
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_x86_64-eng
cd $ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT
emulator
```